# Sass variables with same names but different outcomes based on class?

Tags: html, css, sass

I've tried to wrap my brain round this, I assume that I need an if statement somewhere along the way.

But I'd like to be able to do this with sass. But this will just take the `green` colour and ignore the default colour regardless of the class.

**SASS**

```
//  Default Colours --------------------------------------------------------------
     $textColor: #FFF; 

.green {
   //  Base Colours --------------------------------------------------------------
     $textColor: green; 
}

body {
    text: $textColor
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p>jamie</P> //Output is #FFF

<p class="green">jamie</P> //Output is green
```

Comment: Why would you expect this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little mixin you could use.

```
$base-color: green;

@mixin change-var($var: $base_color, $selector: x, $property: color) {

    @if $selector == x {
        $var: blue;
    } @else if $selector == y {
        $var: green
    } @else {
        $var: $var;
    }

    #{$property}: $var; 
}
```

usage:

```
.x {
    @include change-var($base-color, x, color)
}
.y {
    @include change-var($base-color, y, background-color)
}
```

output:

```
.x {
  color: blue;
}

.y {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$textColor: #fff; 
body {
  color: $textColor;
}
.green {
  $textColor: green; 
  color: $textColor;
}
```

Comment: This will permanently overwrite `$textColor` with the value of `green`.